# removing line by line from textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hello I'm doing a script that checks the value entered in the text area line by line after that sending the response, however what I'm seeing in my code is that all the lines are removed at once, and after that the responses start coming i don't want that what i want is:

```
TextArea One:
Value1
Value2
Value3
```

After checking (Value1) get the response and remove it from the text area so it will be

```
TextArea One:
Value2
Value3
```

and as i was saying the code is removing everything after that start getting the response and this is the code that i tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function(){  
$('#linewhichischeckednowhide').slideDown();    


function removeResourceLine()
{
resource.splice(0, 1);
$('#resource').val(resource.join("\n"));
}
function removeSocksLine()
{
socks.splice(0, 1);
$('#socks').val(socks.join("\n"));
}   


function Result(type,data)
{
$('#'+type).append("<br />"+data);      
}

function whenToChangeSocks()
{
if(maxFail == timeToChangeSocks){maxFail = 0;removeSocksLine()}
}
// Functions are up


//this section only for code variables and code execution

success: function(data)
{
resource.splice(0, 1);
$('#resource').val(resource.join("\n"));    
}   


}).complete(function(){
});



});

});
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok let's talking about the concept cause there are some things not clearly in your question

1st : split textarea value by \n to get rows

2nd : use `$.each()` to loop through array to get each row value

3rd : use each value as you want *(split it or anything)* and post it with ajax

4th : in ajax success just replace the value with ('')  *(check demo)*

this is just a simple example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').on('click',function(){
        var valueSplit = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
        $.each(valueSplit , function(key , value){
            alert(key + value);
            // you can use ajax here for each value
        });
    });
});
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/k54onvyy/3/)

Comment: It is ok Mohamed :) i just took $.each from your code and it works great thank you

Comment: @SniperCoder Good luck .. and have a nice day :)

Comment: Mohamed there is a small problem, since I'm deleting a line foreach check, the (key) must stay 0 however in $.each the key is increasing i want to keep it 0 how i can do that?

Comment: @SniperCoder I don't know how to use the Key in your code .. And I think you will just use the value .. but if you want to keep it 0 don't use it .. just use another variable  var Newkey = 0; and use it instead of key

Comment: @SniperCoder I think this demo will help you http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/k54onvyy/3/

Comment: unfortunately when i removed the alert function the problem started again whenever i click on submit the lines on text area disappear directly and after that the response start to come

Comment: What i meant is that i want after getting the response by ajax, then remove the line that was checked and rapt the check again for the other line?

Comment: @SniperCoder did you saw my last demo in last comment??

Comment: Yes i did, it did not work my brother look simply what i want to do. Take the first line....check it....get response.....remove it....start again...however this code is deleting all the lines at once after that it is starting getting response.

Comment: @SniperCoder please can you update your answer with last code you have and explain what happened with you .. it will be clear to see what is going on .. or if you need to post it as a new question  its up to you .. but I'm sure my code will work like you said .. but let's see your new code

Comment: @SniperCoder in your code  each() doesn't work cause you not using a loop you just use a specific values each time  resource[0] , devidelist[0] , devidelist[1] and socks[0] .. so how the code can loop??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95826/discussion-between-snipercoder-and-mohamed-yousef).

Comment: I'm trying to fix it, i did (key;value) and when u use value the data does not come in order!

Comment: @SniperCoder you should know that's no problem at all to use $.each inside $.each  that mean you can use var devidelist = value.replace(/ +/g, "").split(delim);  and then use another $.each(devidelist , function(key1 , value1)) and use ajax on it  .. this is just if you need to do this